# Why did I get an error when using GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, guzzle

The code I use displays an error.

```
require 'api/vendor/autoload.php';
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => '1400',
        'client_secret' => '2fIcQ0M4оHgrX63B09UW8z521bnGpTNw3LxvQweh',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://example.com/',
        'code' => $code,
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ]
]);

return json_decode($response->getBody())->access_token;
```

Documentation: https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/oauth/authorization-code-grant#converting-authorization-codes-to-access-tokens

I should have ended up with `access_token` but got an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: "POST https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token" resulted in a "400 Bad Request" response: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server." (truncated...) in C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3 C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() # in C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113`

Comment: Googling returns a lot of results focused on if content-type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`. If their docs don't work maybe open an issue on their github. Not jumping out at me but haven't interacted much with laravel/passport/artisan, or whatever exavtly spits out that message.

Comment: `form_params` makes it send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I think this should rather be using the `json` request option, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json

Comment: Can you try to handle the exception using try-catch block?